# SharedPreferences class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I'm creating an app which ask the first time user to input a password. However whenever I press the Submit button the application stops and I think it's because of the class I made for he SharedPreferences. I don't know what to put in the class. Need some help please. Thanks

```
package com.android.steg;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Password extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
Button submitButton;
EditText passwordEditText;
private SharedPreferences SharedPreference;
public static final String PREFS_PRIVATE = "PREFS_PRIVATE";
public static final String KEY_PRIVATE = "KEY_PRIVATE";
public static final String PREFS_READ = "PREFS_READ";
public static final String KEY_READ = "KEY_READ";
public static final String PREFS_WRITE = "PREFS_WRITE";
public static final String KEY_WRITE = "KEY_WRITE";
public static final String PREFS_READ_WRITE = "PREFS_READ_WRITE";
public static final String KEY_READ_WRITE = "KEY_READ_WRITE";



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pass);
    Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{ 
    EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs_file",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String password = prefs.getString("password","");
    if(password=="")
    {
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString("password",passwordEditText.getText().toString());
        edit.commit();
        StartMain();
    }
    else
    {
        if(passwordEditText.getText().toString()== password)
        {
             StartMain();
        }
    }

}

public void StartMain()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}
 }
```

Whenever I press the submit button, it won't send me to the start the MainActivity class.

Comment: Can't you Java Preferences package backed by a persistent storage instead of your custom preferences class?

Comment: How can I use the Java Preferences package? Sorry, I'm just a newbie on android..

Comment: Could you please post some code, and the error message, if it was appearing? This would help to better understand your exact problem.

Comment: @Jonatha Roth: I posted the code.

Comment: As a side note, instead of SharedPreferences prefs = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs_file",MODE_PRIVATE);, you can use SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs_file",MODE_PRIVATE); since an Activity is a Context.

Comment: check whether the onClick and startMain methods are called and please post your results. Replace `password==""` with `password.equals""`

Comment: @Jonathan Roth: The MainActivity class?

Comment: in this code snippet, you posted (Password Activity).

Comment: @Jonathan Roth: How could I check if the methods are called?

Comment: @CoolBeans This is Android, he is using the standard Android preferences package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not comparing `Strings` correctly.  Replace

```
if(password=="")
```

with

```
if("".equals(password))
```

and

```
if(passwordEditText.getText().toString()== password)
```

with

```
if(passwordEditText.getText().toString().equals(password))
```

**EDIT**
The reason you need to make these changes is that `(password=="")` will always be `false`, so the `else` block will always execute.  Within the `else` block, the only test is `(passwordEditText.getText().toString()== password)` and this will **also** always be `false`.  As such, the two calls to `StartMain()` are both within unreachable code blocks and are never executed.  You can easily demonstrate this by putting a bunch of `Log.d("MY_TAG","message goes here");` lines in the various `if` and `else` blocks.

**EDIT 2**
Ah. Woops.  There is an additional issue with the code that I was blinded to by the obviousness of the `String` comparison issue.  You are confusing the scope of your button declaration.  You first define it for the class:

```
Button submitButton;
```

The you redefine it within `onCreate()`:

```
Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
```

Change this last line to:

```
submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
```

Comment: in case of `password==""` returning null, would this also skip the else part?

Comment: `password==""` returns either `true` or `false`, not `null`.  Perhaps you mean if `password` **is** `null`?  If so then both the original test and my suggested replacement would both return `false`.

Comment: I think, that the method startMain() is always called, not dependent on what `password=""` returns, so actually the wrong comparison of strings can´t be the solution in this case, right?

Comment: @Jonathan Roth I've updated my answer with an additional explanation of why I think the changes are needed.

Comment: To expand on dave.c's answer:  The == does a compare, meaning it compares the object on either side of the == and returns whether or not they are the same OBJECT.  You are wanting to compare VALUE, which is why you need to use the .equals method.

Comment: @dave: why is it everytime I press the button Submit the application forces to close?

Comment: @schadi Added a further update.  Hopefully this one fixes it!